# Где купить сервер?

Tags: сервер, железо

Я ни разу не покупал сервера, а вот тут появилась необходимость.
Естественно магазины типа компьютерного мира не подходят для этого.
Нужен юнитовый корпус и т.д.

Собственно интересно узнать где такие покупают, какие особенности при покупке и т.д.

Comment: Покупка пройдет скорее всего на следующей неделе)
Если никто не подскажет сделаю ответ в виде отчета)
Постараюсь с фото)

Comment: А какой сервак нужен? У меня есть 2u, могу продать :)

Comment: Что за сервак и почем?)

Comment: HP на оригинальных сказях, 4 винта по 300гиг, по-моему. Точно сказать не могу, давно не открывал.
Отдам за 1,5к$ или 45000руб.

Посмотреть состояние можно, подъезжайте и смотрите, вроде в одном городе живем :)

Сколько чего там внутри точнее смогу сказать когда буду дома.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, для начала надо определиться с требованиями к железу и выбрать нужную модель. Например, если вы рассматриваете вариант - сервер HP, то можете повыбирать [здесь](http://welcome.hp.com/country/ru/ru/smb/servers.html). Выбрав нужную модель и комплектацию, можно нажать там кнопку и попасть в поиск партнёров и найти продавцов. Нечто подобное обычно бывает и у других поставщиков.

Вообще, разных предложений море. Вот, например: http://www.datasystems.ru/dir_servers.htm или тут http://www.knsneva.ru/vcd-14020/catalog.html.

Ещё вы можете поискать продавцов через Яндекс Маркет в категории [Серверы](http://market.yandex.ru/search.xml?hid=91012), выбрав нужные параметры (не забудьте выбрать свой регион). Например, с [такими параметрами](http://market.yandex.ru/search.xml?hid=91012&onstock=1&manufacturer_warranty=1&glfilter=6178954:6178955,6178956,6178980,6185545&glfilter=6178991:6179010,6179032&glfilter=6179043:400,).